# "Bad with something" or "bad at something"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, adjectives, dialects, at-with

In [a question on Spanish.StackExchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/581/translating-im-bad-with-remembering-something), a question came up about expressing that you are bad at remembering or doing something. Is one "bad *at* something" or "bad *with* something" (nouns)? What about "bad *at* doing something" vs. "bad *with* doing something" (verbs)? If there are regional differences, what are they?

Examples:

- I'm bad with names.
- I'm bad at names.
- I'm bad with cooking.
- I'm bad at cooking.

Comment: +1 Interesting question. They are both used, but used differently. Most (if not all) cases have one that should be used, but I'm hard pressed to think up a case where using the "wrong" one would truly be wrong and/or not be understood.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

My initial thought is that *bad at* (or *good at*) is followed by a word that describes some kind of activity and that *bad with* (or *good with*), is followed by the name of a thing or a type of person. It works with at least the following:

***Bad at**: swimming, math, lying, football, acting, planning, French, cooking, chess*

***Bad with**: children, his hands, money, computers, foreigners, figures, animals*

Comment: @Jasper Loy: In BrEng, at least, you might hear, if not 'I'm bad with computers', then 'I'm no good with computers'.

Comment: I agree there's a strong tendency. To be honest, I'd have thought it would be easier to kick it around with **good** rather than **bad** - it's probably more common overall, and I very much doubt there are any specific things/activities where the preferred preposition changes according to whether one is *good* or *bad* at/with them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Agreed. As I've suggested, 'not good at/with' may be more frequent than 'bad at/with'. In saying that, it's occurred to me that we're just as likely to say 'no good at/with'.

Comment: "Bad at *verbal noun*", "Bad with *noun*"?

Comment: @zzzzBov: '-ing' form always preceded by 'good/bad at'? Probably. But 'good/bad at' is not always followed by an '-ing' form.

Answer (score 5):

These are very similar. Good/bad *with* shades towards naturalness and affinity, or lack thereof. A person who is good/bad *with* computers is able to relate to them comfortably. Good/bad *at* shades towards skill or competence, or lack thereof. A person who is good/bad *at* computers is able to operate them competently.

Consider that a person who is bad *with* children might not relate to them well, but a person who is bad *at* children might have difficulty conceiving.

Answer (score 4):

The idiom is usually "bad at", which can be used with either the activity "bad at cooking" or the objects of it "bad at curries".

"Bad with" is rather less common, and always refers to something used or encountered in an activity, not the activity itself or (usually) its results: "bad with recipes".

Comment: I think maybe we only accept *bad at [noun]* when it's implicitly short for *bad at making [curries]*. Otherwise @Barrie seems to be right that it's generally *at activity/verb* as opposed to *with noun*.

Answer (score 2):

For "regular nouns", there seems to be a pretty even divide between

- Good/Bad ***with*** a thing sounding best
- Good/Bad ***at*** a thing sounding best
- Both ***with*** *and* ***at*** sounding fine

(Barrie England's examples for instance all look right to me)

But for *gerunds*, verbs ending with *-ing* that then function as nouns

- Only good/bad ***at*** doing sounds right

(At least in Australian English but I think in British and American too...)